# Parse.com pointer data for updating tables using Android

Tags: android, pointers, parse-platform

I am making an application for saving user information. I have successfully updated my manual table "UserInfo". Now I want to get the data from that table by using Current User Phenomena. My code snippet is given below:

```
final ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
user.put("firstName", fName.getText().toString());
                    user.put("lastName", lName.getText().toString());
                    user.put("email", mailText.getText().toString());

// Here I am updating data in UserInfo Table, I want to get
// values from this table now, I mean I want to retrieve data here.

final ParseObject update = new ParseObject("UserInfo");

update.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException arg0) {
                        update.put("doctor", doInfo.getText().toString());
                        update.put("medi", medtion.getText().toString());
                        update.put("icalNote", medNotes.getText().toString());
                        update.put("meCondition", medCond.getText().toString());
                        update.put("agies", agiesReact.getText().toString());
                        update.saveInBackground();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

in your UserInfo class you add new field 'ptrUser' that is type pointer and that has value = getCurrentUser().

When you have saved the UserInfo  with the ptr field, you can do a flat query retreiving both of the classes

in REST API idiom :

```
GET ./classes/UserInfo/null?include=ptrUser
```

SDK idiom:

```
query.include($ptrUser)
```